# Can't signIn in android studio or IntelliJ idea

Tags: android, android-studio, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-api

I'm trying to signIn android studio with my google account.
[image]

but I'm getting this error message.

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_scope
>
> Some requested scopes cannot be shown:
>   [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting,
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin,
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud_debugger]
>
> Request Details
>   client_id=4086593417-gf2guk0f0f5eqigaplgehmf8v00vl.apps.googleusercontent.com
>
> That’s all we know.

[image]

I also tried IntelliJ idea with the same result.
I changed from chrome to edge.
I tried a different account.
I even tried with my friend laptop.

I don't know if this related to google servers or my machine.

Comment: also experiencing this problem. Myversion is Android Studio 3.0 beta 1

Comment: This is fixed in the [17.8.2 release](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8079-google-cloud-tools/update/37705) of the IntelliJ plugin.

Comment: add your comment as an answer and I will accept it.